# Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform (While it does exits on firestore)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm writing a code in which I'm trying to login admin. And for that I created an Admin on FireStore ,not with code, but with the options that firestore provide. It's like first I made an admin on firestore then I wrote a code in which I'm trying to login that perticular admin by providing the same admin's id and password inside the app. I suppose it is some kind of key issue but I don't know how to handle this error.

**Below is the error when app is used on an Emulator**

[image]
**Below is the error when app is used on Real Android Mobile**

[image]

**And when Click on line #7 it takes me to the file where firestore code is written for admin login.**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

And when I click the below line error(app running on actual phone) it takes me to a firestore snapshot file which I don't understand.
[image]

**FirebaseFirestore console(Here the admin fields are created with the "+" options)**

[image]

**Flutter Doctor**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.450], locale en-PK)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

**AdminLogin.dart**

```
   import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:ecom_app/Authentication/AuthnticationScreen.dart';
import 'package:ecom_app/DialogBox/errordialog.dart';
import 'package:ecom_app/Widgets/CustomTextField.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Uploaditems.dart';


class Adminsignin extends StatelessWidget {
  const Adminsignin({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [Colors.pink,Colors.lightGreenAccent],
                begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
                end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
                stops: [0.0,1.0],
                tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
              )
          ),
        ),
        title: Text
          (
          'E-Shop',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize:55.0,color: Colors.white),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,

      ),
      body: AdminSignInPage(),
    );
  }
}




class AdminSignInPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AdminSignInPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AdminSignInPageState createState() => _AdminSignInPageState();
}

class _AdminSignInPageState extends State<AdminSignInPage> {
  final TextEditingController _adminController =TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController =TextEditingController();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey=GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _screenwidth=MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,_screenHeight=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.pink,Colors.lightGreenAccent],
              begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
              end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
              stops: [0.0,1.0],
              tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
            )
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Image.asset(
                'images/welcome.png',
                height: 240.0,
                width: 240.0,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding:EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text('Admin',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white38,fontSize: 28.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),

            ),

            Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [

                    customtextfield(
                      controller: _adminController,
                      data: Icons.person,
                      hinttext: 'ID',
                      isObsecure:false,
                    ),
                    customtextfield(
                      controller: _passwordController,
                      data: Icons.lock,
                      hinttext: 'Password',
                      isObsecure:true,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 25.0,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: ()=>
                      _adminController.text.isNotEmpty&&_passwordController.text.isNotEmpty
                          ? loginAdmin ()
                          :showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (c){
                            return ErrorDialog(message: 'Please Enter ID and Password');
                          }
                      ),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.pink,onPrimary: Colors.yellow),
                      child:Text("Login"),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50.0,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 4.0,
                      width: _screenwidth*0.8,
                      color: Colors.pink,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    FlatButton.icon(
                      onPressed: (){
                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>AuthenticScreen( )));
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.admin_panel_settings,color: Colors.pink,),
                      label: Text('I am not an Admin',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),

                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50.0,
                    ),

                  ],
                )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  loginAdmin (){
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('admins').get().then((snapshot){
      snapshot.docs.forEach((result){
        if(result['id'] != _adminController.text.trim())
          {
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('ID is not Correct')));
          }
        else if(result['password' != _passwordController.text.trim()])
          {
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Passwod is not Correct')));
          }
        else
          {
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Welcome Admin, ' +result['name'],)));
            setState(() {
              _adminController.text='';
              _passwordController.text='';
            });
            Route route=MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c)=> UploadPage());
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
        }
      });
    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check all field in firestore are the same in your code.
May be this field (Admin) changed to Admins

Comment: The fields in firestore and in code are same checked multiple times. And you can see it as well. Because most of the times, when I searched for the error people say check your fields, so that's why I uploaded my code as well as my firestore fields for you,  And in emulator the app also crashes when I press login button.

Comment: Also please check y updated question as well, I've added another picture of a file, it might help you to understand what mistake I'm doing.

Comment: change this field result['id']  to result['ID'] ,and add this field in firestore 'name'

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. Their were 2 things.

1. I made a mistake by not creating a required field **'name'**. Also you must check that, If you are using small letters in firestore than use small and if your are using capitals, than use capital letters in your code fields as well. **Firestore is sensitive to letter case**
2. In newer version of flutter now the command has changed and now it required a **data()** as well.

**This is the updated code that worked for me**

`if(result['id'] != _adminController.text.trim())`

**is changed to**

`if(result.data()['id'] != _adminController.text.trim())`

```
 loginAdmin () {
         FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('admins').get().then((snapshot){
          snapshot.docs.forEach((result){
            if(result.data()['id'] != _adminController.text.trim())
              {
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('ID is not Correct')));
              }
            else if(result.data()['password'] != _passwordController.text.trim())
              {
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Passwod is not Correct')));
              }
            else
              {
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Welcome Admin, ' +result.data()['name'],)));
                setState(() {
                  _adminController.text='';
                  _passwordController.text='';
                });
                Route route=MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c)=> UploadPage());
                Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
            }
          });
        });
```